# Can't access basic Spotify API data anymore

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, request, spotify

Just since a hour age I can't access anything on the spotify API anymore. Simple request like:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7AGSJihqYPhYy5QzMcwcQT/albums

Do not work anymore. Even if I just place them in the URL in the browser.

Why can't I access basic information like this? Even the Spotify API documentation example link doesnt allow access.

They all say Error 401 - No token provided.

Why? Do I need that token for non-user related information? I didn't need it until an hour ago...

This is the request I made, it worked before. Could someone test it, like visiting the URL in browser?

`reqwest({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7AGSJihqYPhYy5QzMcwcQT/albums',
        type: 'json',
        method: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossOrigin: true,
        error: function (err) { },
        success: getTracks
    });`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED:

I'm just unlucky. Since exactly this day, May 29th 2017, EVERY request needs to be authorized. :(

Comment: Do you have a link to the change announcement for this? I hit the same issue as you.

Comment: Yes - this was announced in January: https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2017/01/27/removing-unauthenticated-calls-to-the-web-api/